# When it comes to mapreduce how are the Accumulo tablets mapped to an HDFS block

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, accumulo

If my environment set up is as follows:
-64MB HDFS block
-5 tablet servers
-10 tablets of size 1GB each per tablet server

If I have a table like below:
rowA | f1 | q1 | v1
rowA | f1 | q2 | v2

rowB | f1 | q1 | v3

rowC | f1 | q1 | v4
rowC | f2 | q1 | v5
rowC | f3 | q3 | v6

From the little documentation, I know all data about rowA will go one tablet which may or may not contain data about other rows ie its all or none. So my questions are:

How are the tablets mapped to a Datanode or HDFS block? Obviously, One tablet is split into multiple HDFS blocks (8 in this case) so would they be stored on the same or different datanode(s) or does it not matter?

In the example above, would all data about RowC (or A or B) go onto the same HDFS block or different HDFS blocks?

When executing a map reduce job how many mappers would I get? (one per hdfs block? or per tablet? or per server?)

Thank you in advance for any and all suggestions.

Comment: Not sure. Out of curiosity, why are you concerned about the number of mappers? In general, you would launch Accumulo scanners to access data in the rows. The scanners provide a level of abstraction, so you don't need to implement MapReduce jobs yourself.

Comment: I am writing mapreduce job that reads from and writes to accumulo tables. In the example above let me call all data from one row, a "record". So I am trying to figure out the order these records would come in. Which of course depends on how spread they are.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions directly:

> How are the tablets mapped to a Datanode or HDFS block? Obviously, One tablet is split into multiple HDFS blocks (8 in this case) so would they be stored on the same or different datanode(s) or does it not matter?

Tablets are stored in blocks like all other files in HDFS. You will typically see all blocks for a single file on at least one data node (this isn't always the case, but seems to mostly hold true when i've looked at block locations for larger files)

> In the example above, would all data about RowC (or A or B) go onto the same HDFS block or different HDFS blocks?

Depends on the block size for your tablets (`dfs.block.size` or if configured the Accumulo property `table.file.blocksize`). If the block size is the same size as the tablet size, then obviously they will be in the same HDFS block. Otherwise if the block size is smaller than the tablet size, then it's pot luck as to whether they are in the same block or not.

> When executing a map reduce job how many mappers would I get? (one per hdfs block? or per tablet? or per server?)

This depends on the ranges you give `InputFormatBase.setRanges(Configuration, Collection<Ranges>)`.

If you scan the entire table (-inf -> +inf), then you'll get a number of mappers equal to the number of tablets (caveated by disableAutoAdjustRanges). If you define specific ranges, you'll get a different behavior depending on whether you've called `InputFormatBase.disableAutoAdjustRanges(Configuration)` or not:

1. If you have called this method then you'll get one mapper per range defined. Importantly, if you have a range that starts in one tablet and ends in another, you'll get one mapper to process that entire range
2. If you don't call this method, and you have a range that spans over tablets, then you'll get one mapper for each tablet the range covers

Answer (score 1):

For writing to Accumulo (data ingest), it makes sense to run MapReduce jobs, where the mapper inputs are your input files on HDFS. You would basically follow this example from Accumulo documentation:

http://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/examples/mapred.html

(Section IV of this paper provides some more background on techniques for ingesting data into Accumulo: http://ieee-hpec.org/2012/index_htm_files/byun.pdf)

For reading from Accumulo (data query), I would not use MapReduce. Accumulo/Zookeeper will automatically distribute your query across tablet servers. If you're using rows as atomic records, use (or extend) the WholeRowIterator and launch a Scanner (or BatchScanner) on the range of rows you're interested in. The Scanner will run in parallel across your tablet servers. You don't really want to access Accumulo data directly from HDFS or MapReduce.

Here's some example code to help get your started:

```
//some of the classes you'll need (in no particular order)...

import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Connector;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Instance;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.Constants;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Scanner;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.IteratorSetting;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Key;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Range;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Value;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

//Accumulo client code...

//Accumulo connection
Instance instance = new ZooKeeperInstance( /* put your installation info here */ );
Connector connector = instance.getConnector(username, password);

//setup a Scanner or BatchScanner
Scanner scanner = connector.createScanner(tableName, Constants.NO_AUTHS);
Range range = new Range(new Text("rowA"), new Text("rowB"));
scanner.setRange(range);

//use a WholeRowIterator to keep rows atomic
IteratorSetting itSettings = new IteratorSetting(1, WholeRowIterator.class);
scanner.addScanIterator(itSettings);

//now read some data!
for (Entry<Key, Value> entry : scanner) {
    SortedMap<Key,Value> wholeRow = WholeRowIterator.decodeRow(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

    //do something with your data!

}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am a newbie to accumulo and map reduce. Do you have any examples to the later I can follow?

Comment: I just edited the answer to include an example of how to set up a Scanner for reading data out of Accumulo.

Comment: Thank you for the example. You said not to use MapReduce to access Accumulo. May be I wasn't clear. I am actually trying to do some mapreduce jobs that will need to access data stored in my accumulo instance and then post-mapreduce write back to another table in accumulo. This is why I was asking how many mappers would there be and in what order the key value pairs would be streamed. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: What do the mappers have to do? Perhaps that work can be implemented as an Accumulo iterator. If not, you'll still probably want your map tasks to read data through Accumulo API (like in my example). And in that case, using Hadoop MapReduce won't buy you much in terms of ensuring processing is local to the data. You might consider writing a threaded or distributed Java app (outside of the MapReduce framework) or maybe you don't even need to use Accumulo.